# String.Replace not working correctly

Tags: c#, replace

This is very odd as I have used the Replace function for thousands of times. This is my code:

```
while (d.IndexOf("--") != -1) d=d.Replace("--", "-");
```

and this is the variable **d**'s value when I trace:

```
"آدنیس,اسم دختر,girl name,آدونیس--‌-گلی-به-رنگ-زرد-و-قرمز-که-فقط-هنگام-تابش-خورشید-باز-می-شود"
```

but it stuck when the value of **d** is:

```
"آدنیس,اسم دختر,girl name,آدونیس-‌-گلی-به-رنگ-زرد-و-قرمز-که-فقط-هنگام-تابش-خورشید-باز-می-شود"
```

can anybody tell me why?
Its funny that even dashes are added programatically.

Comment: sorry - I don't understand why you think this is not working correctly - can you explain more? what does 'it stuck' mean?

Comment: @Stuart The replace is in a loop but the result contains two minuses that do not get replaced.

Comment: @Stuart the loop doesn't stop. the indexOf returns a value different than -1 that is correct but the last "--" doesn't get replaced with "-" so the loop continues

Comment: you realise how hard it is for non arabic readers to see the difference right?

Comment: @Sayse as I have written, "I have used Replace thousands of times". this was the only string that it had problem. so I had to copy the exact text. By the way its not arabic, its Persian, and Im Turkish ;)

Comment: @Sayse by the way I got the answer in 2 minutes and the answerer has used my text and described well. It looks that they all have understood it. so there is no problem.

Comment: My intention was to point out that it would have been cut down the ammount of text showing in your question so its easier to scan over, also there were a lot of characters included that look partially similar to the '-' character, If you had done this you would have received more of a response to your question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is because this:

```
var d1 = "آدنیس,اسم دختر,girl name,آدونیس--‌-گلی-به-رنگ-زرد-و-قرمز-که-فقط-هنگام-تابش-خورشید-باز-می-شود";
```

is not the same as this:

```
var d2 = "آدنیس,اسم دختر,girl name,آدونیس---گلی-به-رنگ-زرد-و-قرمز-که-فقط-هنگام-تابش-خورشید-باز-می-شود";
```

The last three characters in your string are not actually the unicode `-` Try it yourself:

```
var d1 = "آدنیس,اسم دختر,girl name,آدونیس--‌-گلی-به-رنگ-زرد-و-قرمز-که-فقط-هنگام-تابش-خورشید-باز-می-شود";
var d2 = "آدنیس,اسم دختر,girl name,آدونیس---گلی-به-رنگ-زرد-و-قرمز-که-فقط-هنگام-تابش-خورشید-باز-می-شود";
while (d.IndexOf("--", StringComparison.Ordinal) != -1) d1 = d1.Replace("--", "-");
Console.WriteLine(d1); // the last characters are left 
while (d2.IndexOf("--", StringComparison.Ordinal) != -1) d2 = d2.Replace("--", "-");
Console.WriteLine(d2); // All clear
```

Just FYI: 
String comparison method indexof is culture specific. I would use:

```
var d = "آدنیس,اسم دختر,girl name,آدونیس--‌-گلی-به-رنگ-زرد-و-قرمز-که-فقط-هنگام-تابش-خورشید-باز-می-شود";
while (d.IndexOf("--", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) != -1) 
      d = d.Replace("--", "-");
```

Since it uses ordinal rules i.e. culture independent unicode values, and it runs faster.

Comment: greattttttt, I have used indexOf alot but never had this problem. Thanks alot

Comment: i have tried this code but it seems it's not working in my compiler, what am I missing? http://i.stack.imgur.com/jxswx.jpg

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Regex.Replace()`

```
string _txt = "----------";
_txt = Regex.Replace(_txt, @"\-{2,}", "-");
```

this will output: `-`

Comment: thanks a lot this solves my problem but i'm really confused could you tell me what is the problem with the replace?

Comment: the `replace` or `regex.replace`?

Comment: oh i tried to debug the code, i am not expert with this but i did an infinite loop using the string on the question. maybe it has something to do with the encoding.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested this with LinqPad - interesting.

```
// d0 succeeds:
var d0 = "world--life";

while (d0.IndexOf("--") != -1) 
{
    d0=d0.Replace("--", "-");
    d0.Dump();
}

// d1 loops forever
var d1 = "world--life";

while (d1.IndexOf("--") != -1) 
{
    d1=d1.Replace("-‌-", "-");
    d1.Dump();
}
```

The difference between the two loops is that while they may appear identical, the second loop actually uses different Unicode characters for the hyphens in `IndexOf` to the ones in `Replace`

Looking at the MSDN docs:

- IndexOf - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx - `This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) search using the current culture. The search begins at the first character position of this instance and continues until the last character position.`
- Replace - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx - `This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) search to find oldValue.`

So the difference is **culture-insensitive** versus **culture-sensitive**

Comment: I got the answer, it was interesting. have a look at it.

Comment: i didn't spot the difference between two loops